Documentary about an atheist going back to his christian school?
I am trying to find a documentary about an atheist who goes back to his christian school. In the beginning of the documentary, there is a scene which shows many pictures of christians smiling, and the narrarator says something along the lines of "These people look happy. I want to be happy like them." Then the pictures change to right-wing christian terrorists. Around the middle, the narrator visits his old christian school and has an interview with the principal. However, when the narrator starts asking questions such as "Isn't it child abuse to teach children about hell?" the principal promptly ends the interview, saying the narrator was dishonest in his set-up of the interview. As the narrator is leaving the school grounds, he stops by the chapel which he used to attend when he was a student. At the very end of the documentary, the narrator (still inside the chapel) says "I blaspheme the holy spirit" and  the documentary ends.

I'd say the documentary you are looking for is The God Who Wasn't There. It's a little over the half way mark and the narrator is talking to a head of the school he attended. He is asked to turn off the camera and he says basically no lets just keep talking and the head fellow says some thing like "you have been dishonest setting up this interview". At the start of the film after smiling people he says " how am I not this happy, I want to be happy". It then shows some less than shining examples of people with faith.  

